# How to get CSV integers read as integers from a string variable

Tags: php, max, min

I have a string that I get from sanitizing some values from an xml file.

```
$resolutions=strip_tags($resolutions,allow);  // gives me '75 75 300 300 600 600'
```

Then I change the spaces to commas:

```
$resolutions = preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($resolutions)); // gives me '75,75,300,300,600,600'
```

Then I take that and want to extract min and max values like this

```
$resolution_min = min($resolutions);
```

on the page for display

```
echo $resolution_min; // still gives me '75,75,300,300,600,600'
```

However when I  change the code where I want it displayed on the page

```
 echo min(75,75,300,300,600,600);  // it displays '75' as it should
```

I think, the issue is that the CSV values are being interpreted as a single text string and I need them read as CSV integer values.

Is there some way to force these to be read as numeric values by min and max?

I think part of my problem comes from this line or a line like it, jus befor an "explode" command

```
$list = "" . substr($scansupportedresolutions, $start,$length) . "";
```

I have never seen this kind of double double quote dot and dot double double quote and have no idea what it means

Is it simply saying the entire string in $list will be

```
".<CONTENT HERE>."
```

but specifically in double quotes? Whatever it is i seems crucial to the explode command.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

Comment: Instead of `preg_replace` use `preg_split`

Comment: Warning: min(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 3):

From [min](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php):

> If the first and only parameter is an array, min() returns the lowest value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, min() returns the smallest of these values.

You are passing one parameter and it's a string.  Pass an array:

```
$resolutions = explode(',', $resolutions);
$resolution_min = min($resolutions);
```

Comment: AbraCadaver that now give me 0 , but thanks anyway. I did test like that as well. I also tried min(array($var)). I have even confirmed the array by print_r($arrayname) . Value shown is '0' for bothmin and max.

Comment: @TeknoGeekz then your $resolutions did likely not contain the comma-separated integers in string form at this point. Did you leave your preg_replace that replaces the white space with comma in, or …?

Comment: Show `var_dump($resolutions);` after the `strip_tags` and before anything else.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by after strip_tags , but I did a var dump to screen, and then view source I see this array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "300"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "300"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "600"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "600"
}

Comment: Yes commas were left in place. Also that is a slightly different source than the original. This one has no "75" values

Comment: So maybe you have things out of order, not sure: https://3v4l.org/jTrqO

Answer (score 0):

AbraCadaver is correct in his answer.

I have tried to improve your code. Take a look

```
<?php
// After Stripping tag
$resolutions = "75 75 300 300 600 600";
// No need to conver to Space to comma
$resolutionsArray = explode(" ", $resolutions); 
$resolutionMin = min($resolutionsArray);
print($resolutionMin);
```

There is no gain by converting the "white Space" to "Comma". You can explode the string into array by setting "white Space" as delimiter.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to contributing at Stack Overflow. Please describe exactly how your code is an improvement; blocks of code with no explanation are not of much use.

Comment: I have concluded that there is something more going on than I understand. Perhaps way beyond me. I am adding a line of code to OP maybe someone can tell me about these double double quotes?

Comment: Those double  quotes have space in between as delimiter.